# Changing class attrib of element still calling old event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario**

I have anchor with `class=anchor` and clicking it will change it's own class to `anchor2`. Two click event: `anchor & anchor2` will `alert($(this).attr('id'))`.

**Problem**

The problem is, after changing it's class to `anchor2`, it still calling the old event which alerting the `anchor2 class`.

What's going on? https://jsfiddle.net/3kzs7n9r/13/

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" class="anchor">Click me</a>

<script>
    $('.anchor').on('click', function () {
      alert('anchor clicked with class: '+$(this).attr('class'));
      $(this).attr('class', 'anchor2');
    });

    $('.anchor2').on('click', function () {
      alert('anchor clicked with class: '+$(this).attr('class'));
      $(this).attr('class', 'anchor');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Two click events for one element! Why?

Comment: @Sagar apprently, I can just create two `anchors` and do the hide & show. But I'm just curious why this kind of logic won't work. Or did I just miss something?

Comment: @LekzFlores check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register your click event differently, as when you are registering the anchor2 event that element is not present on DOM.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.anchor', function () {
      alert('anchor clicked with class: '+$(this).attr('class'));
      $(this).attr('class', 'anchor2');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.anchor2', function () {
      alert('anchor clicked with class: '+$(this).attr('class'));
      $(this).attr('class', 'anchor');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

find the below snippet it may help you
instead of having click event for CLASS. making it for ID it will as you required
on click check condition and then based on condition change class

```js
$('#anchor').on('click', function () {
 alert('anchor clicked with class: '+$(this).attr('class'));
  if($(this).hasClass("anchor")){
   $(this).removeClass('anchor').addClass('anchor2');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('anchor2').addClass('anchor');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="anchor" id="anchor">Click me</a>
```